# Can Heroku be made to use a persistent filesystem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I've built an app where users can upload their avatars. I used the paperclip gem and everything works fine on my local machine. On Heroku everything works fine until server restart. Then every uploaded images disappear. Is it possible to keep them on the server?

Notice: I probably should use services such as Amazon S3 or Google Cloud. However each of those services require credit card or banking account information, even if you want to use a free mode. This is a small app just for my portfolio and I would rather avoid sending that information.

Comment: You could use dropbox (Free) and it seems at least someone has written an ActiveStorage library for it [activestorage-dropbox](https://github.com/ashishprajapati/activestorage-dropbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and there is no way to make it persistent. You will lose your uploads every time your [dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

You must [use an off-site file storage service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) if you want to store files long-term.

(Technically you could store your images directly in your database, e.g. as a [`bytea` in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html), but I *strongly* advise against that. It's not very efficient and then you have to worry about how to provide the saved files to the browser. Go with S3 or something similar.)

Comment: Thank you Chris. Is it possible to use any of those services without passing them my credit card number? Even if they have free plans most of them require it.

Comment: I don't know. It sounds like you _have_ a credit card number, you just don't want to provide it. This will just take a few minutes and is relatively low-risk. I suggest you just go for it.